# Can you ask a question because you're curious?

Tags: discussion, questions

Is it ok to ask a question (and a good one! A question that requires knowledge just to understand) just because you're curious?

I mean, the question is not related to my job, it is interesting in itself, but it is not a *problem* that I am dealing with; it is not going to help me progress in my actual programing, but it sure will be useful or interesting knowledge to share, plus knowing how things work in the background. It seems to be hard to answer a question that is not based on a real life problem.

In such cases, is it ok to ask the question or should I just stick to asking a question about real troubles I'm dealing with?

That is, knowing the question have only one true answer, so it cannot be considered too braod.

Comment: Well you shouldn't be asking questions that are about you-you-you, you should be asking questions which are good questions that will help multiple people. You being curious or you having a problem are only triggers for a question, they don't make the quality of a question.

Comment: If it's a good question per the quality guidelines, Stack won't care where the question came from or why you're asking it. If it is a good, complete, on topic question.... Just ask

Comment: As Patrice said, a good question is a good question. Simple as that. However, being something you're just curious about sounds like a good set up for a bad question. If it's nothing you're working on in one way or another, then you likely haven't tried anything and don't have a good example to ask about. Tread lightly.

Comment: We don't really have a way to know your motives. Maybe it's homework. Maybe it's for your job. Maybe you just want the rep from asking good questions. Maybe you're just curious. Maybe you're settling a bet. We don't care, as long as it's a good question.

Comment: Is it on topic?

Comment: Exept the questions i was talking about have only one true answer, it is not broad...

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If it is not a duplicate and well formed of course you can. When you think others can learn from it and the answer of this.

Sometimes they won't help many people but there are lots of people who are really "in depth" in a language and such corner cases interest them. So I would encourage you to do this. Just make sure it is well presented and you had put some research into it so people will not be like *"what you are trying to do is stupid"*.

Example: 
[int a[] = {1,2,}; Weird comma allowed. Any particular reason?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7043372/int-a-1-2-weird-comma-allowed-any-particular-reason)

This will probably not help many people. But the ones passionate about the language find this interesting and it has quite some upvotes because it is interesting.

Comment: @Antoine Yeah. just by searching for a highscored question in the language lawyer tag I learned something new. While it seems "useless" in the question/title the answers provide insight of a feature I did not now of (until now). That is why such questions can have a lot of value.

Comment: @Hayt You should not equate votes with value.  Most of those posts have the score they do because they were entertaining, not because they were useful.  Posts like these are in fact *actively harmful* in many cases, as they end up drawing people away from post with actual value and spending that time on pure entertainment.

Comment: @Servy are our votes not the tool to indicate value? But in the example I posted the person who asked the question most likely did not know if it will result in value. Sometimes you have to ask and wait for the answers. Because the value can be added with the answers not the question sometimes. I would encourage to ask and maybe have a question without value over not asking and potentially have missing value.

Comment: Votes are *supposed* to be used to indicate value.  Not everyone actually votes that way in practice.  Many people upvote content that they found entertaining, even though it was not actually useful to them.  It is one of the places where votes break down on this site.  Telling people to ask bad questions "because maybe someone will post a good answer anyway" is *horrible* advice.  The site is *built* around getting people to ask good quesitons.

Comment: I never said asking a bad question should be done. I also mentioned multiple times (as the comments) that the question should be well formulated and have some research behind it etc. I just don't think that you should actually have a problem. Sometimes you try things out and wonder why things don't work or work differently. When you try enough and isolate the issue and don't find anything on it, I don't see an issue with posting it here. Even if you don't *need* the answer.

Comment: @Hayt You said that the question shouldn't be useful.  That makes the question a bad question, if it can't be helpful to anyone to know the answer.  Doing research is a prerequisite for a good question, but it is not *sufficient* for being a good question.

Comment: @Servy then what ? If i ask a question that is actualy interesting, well formulated, but not helping my case, i should not ask it here ? Where then ? Because i did search for the answer i couldn't find it anywhere but i i'm still curious !

Comment: How do you know it is not useful? You never know if the answers have some useful information for people or not before you ask. The more knowledge you have in a language the better you can judge it. But there are mechanisms on stackoverflow to deal with useless questions. There are no mechanisms here to deal with questions not asked.

Comment: @Antoine If you ask a question that is interesting, well formulated, but not a practical programming problem *then it is off topic here*.  Consider posting it on another site where such a question would be on topic.  If you have a question about a practical problem, but simply aren't faced with that problem yourself, then the question is fine.

Comment: @Hayt You stated as an assumption that the question doesn't need to be useful.  It does.  Your assertion that it's okay to ask bad questions, "because you don't know that it's a bad question until you ask it" is false.  You don't ask any and every question because it *might* be useful, rather, you only ask questions that you *know* are useful.  That's what makes it a good question.  SO isn't a site where you ask anything and everything and see what happens; it's a site where questions need to be good questions to be asked.

Comment: @Servy I agree you should not ask anything all the time. You should put some time into it beforehand and mostly you get the answer by that. Who judges if something is an "impractical" question? you? alone? I think this is  subjective. A voting system would be nice to see what the majority says ;) But you can only vote on the question once it has been posted. We can agree to disagree, but I just personally will never discourage anyone to ask a question someone has invested time in to research and is well presented. If it does not fit it will be dealt with later.

Comment: @Hayt I didn't say I was the judge of whether a question was practical.  Your assertion that it shouldn't be is completely wrong, as the help center *specifically* said that questions need to be about practical problems.  It's not a matter of opinion.  It's a straight fact, and your assertion to the contrary is, as a result, provably wrong.  The fact that you don't care if someone asks a question that's off topic doesn't make that question on off topic, and it doesn't make it appropriate for you to tell people that they should be posting off topic questions.

Comment: Can i assume this ? if the question is not a good one, it will probably get down voted or closed anyway ? because there is definitly only one answer to the said question even though it is based on curiosity, the answer is also going to make me gain knowledge and even those that have reached the question could learn something from it, but not going to be that much practical in everyday use, just being aware of what's in the background. Then what ? Ask elsewhere ?

Comment: @Antoine Like I've said, if your question has no practical applications *then it is off topic here*, and it's not appropriate for you to ask it.

Comment: Well, in my case, It COULD have a practical application, but i doubt anyone cares, i might just ask it elsewhere.

Comment: @Antoine just ask. and see the results. Without you posting the question you may never know. It might be on topic and it might be off topic. The fact that you went to meta first and asked suggest that you know your way around here, And you dont need a job "problem" to ask your question, Just asks and it will be dealt with. Even what other people think "impractical" can be practical to others. So it is a matter of opinion and let the votes speak for themself. The fact that you asked herer in the first place suggests that you are aware enough of the rules.

Comment: @Hayt That's not how SO works.  It's not an, "ask whatever you feel like, it doesn't matter what" type of site.  There are lots of sites like that, where you can ask whatever you want, regardless of scope, quality, etc. and where there are no real site guidelines.  This is not one of those places.  People are expected to ask quality questions, they're expected to meet various guidelines as to what an appropriate question is.  Telling people to just ignore them and post the question anyway is extremely inappropriate behavior.  It's also a good way to get other people question banned.

Answer (score 8):

Questions need to be (as is described in the help center) "a **practical**, answerable problem that is unique to software development" (emphasis mine).  Now, it's perfectly appropriate to ask a question that *you personally* don't have a practical use for, but the question should still be *of practical use to someone*.  The best example of this is self answered questions.

Often (not always, but often enough) when someone is posting an answer along with their question *they* don't actually have that particular problem, they're simply providing information so that it can help others.  That they personally didn't have a practical use for the answer doesn't mean somebody else couldn't.

But to ask a question that *couldn't* have practical value; that *nobody* would be able to actually use, would be off topic here.  (It *might* be on topic on one of the other sites that focus on more theoretical concepts, but you'd need to look into them specifically to see if your question would apply.)

Given all of this, it's certainly going to be a lot less risky to ask questions for problems for which you actually need a solution for in practice.  If you don't actually have a practical need for the answer you could very easily end up asking a question that doesn't have practical value.  It's not *impossible* for it to have practical value, it's just difficult to ask such questions (and ask them well) so you should certainly be very careful when asking such questions.

Comment: But this kind of questions *are* allowed! "I tried `x` but it did not work, so I used `y` instead. Why did `x` not work?" No ,practical' use, as the issue was resolved?

Comment: @RadLexus The person asking such a question might not need the solution to that problem, as they've found another solution, but the question is still practical in the sense that others could easily have that problem and need a solution for it.  I covered as much in my answer.

Comment: no the question was about "i found something I am curious about". There was never a mention about another practical better solution

Comment: @Hayt There was in Rad's example situation.